# Cannot start nuxt: Maximum call stack size exceeded (only when ELSINT plugin is enabled)

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, eslint

I'm trying to run `npm run dev`but i got this error, when i disable `"@nuxtjs/eslint-module"` in my `nuxt.config.json` i don't get the problem.

[error in console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zin9E.png)